# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace' in Python list comprehension

Tags: json, list, python-2.7, dictionary, nonetype

I have the folllowing dictionary...

```
mydict = {'columns': ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
          'rows': [['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
                   ['testing data 1', 'testing data 2lk\nIdrjy9dyj', 'testing data 3'],
                   ['testing data 2', 'testing data 3', 'testing data 4'],
                   ['testing data 3', 'testing data 4', 'testing data 5']]}
```

And I am using the following list comprehension to replace carriage return `"\n"` with this `"<br>"`. It works fine except when it gets passed an empty string  as it is reading a json file. Then it throws the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'`. I just do not know how to put a `if is not none` statement in the list comprehension. Any help greatly appreciated..

```
for items in mydict['rows']:
        mydict['rows'][i] = [item.replace("\n","<br>") for item in items]
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a boolean expression here:

```
[item and item.replace("\n","<br>") for item in items]
```

This only calls `item.replace()` if `item` is considered true; `None` and an empty string are both considered false.

If you wanted to *filter out* any `None` items you could add a test to your list comprehension:

```
[item.replace("\n","<br>") for item in items if item is not None]
```

to remove `None` values or

```
[item.replace("\n","<br>") for item in items if item]
```

to only keep non-empty values.

Comment: That is slick! Thank you